# Load a GML file in GeoServer and serve it over WFS

Tags: geoserver, gml

I would like to understand if it is possible to load a GML file in GeoServer and serve it over WFS.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to load a GML file into [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org). GML is a transport format not a storage format as while it compresses easily it has no indexing and as a text format is very hard to search efficiently.

You can use [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to convert your GML into an number of formats that GeoServer can serve as WFS layers. The most efficient would be to store the data in a well indexed [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was asking that because actually deegree is providing as option a GML storage. The problem of deegree is that it has no GeoJSON output formato for a WFS service.